# I can't use my nvidia gpu

Tags: graphics, display

I have a laptop with ryzen 5 4600H cpu and nvidia gtx 1650 gpu, a week ago everything was fine but for a few days i can't get output on my monitor, and normally there were more options on nvidia x server settings, i don't get the options anymore after this problem. I tried reinstalling the drivers but didn't work. [Nvidia settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRytf.png)

I get this output from "xrandr --listproviders"

```
Providers: number : 0
```

It was 2 before the problem, is there anyway i can fix this or i should make a clean install?

AMD gpu doesn't work on my external monitor, i am using the nvidia gpu because amd gpu shows white screen on external monitor and if there is any way to use it on external monitors please let me know.

I didn't even install something or changed any files or settings, i just woke up and turned my pc on but i couldn't see anything on my computer. And everything works fine on my windows by the way, i use dual boot. If anyone knows how to fix this issue please help me, thanks in advance^^

Comment: You don't seem to have any nvidia drivers installed.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't logged in using Wayland instead of xorg?  Click on the little gear in the lower right corner of the login screen when the password field is visible, choose the non-wayland or the xorg version.

Comment: I saw the gear on the bottom right corner once on the login screen and i selected xorg but i still see the wayland as windowing system and it is super laggy on lock screen, i deleted some config files before to resolve this issue may it caused this problem? I deleted some configs from "usr/share/x11/xorg.conf.d/" path, thanks for your answer

Comment: I edited "/etc/gdm3/custom.conf" and disabled wayland and installed nvidia driver 525 now i got  "Providers: number : 1" but still i can't get output on my external monitor 